# Extjs Combo diplay value - if value is not found

Tags: javascript, extjs, autocomplete

I am using this technique to accomplish an auto-complete feature for a combo box http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/form/forum-search.html , it returns name and type of a car, sometimes the type is unknown so nothing returns, I would like it to be "No Data" so I used this `valueNotFoundText: 'No Data'` but didn't work

```
xtype: 'combo',
store: s,
hideTrigger:true,
typeAhead: false,
id: 'search',
queryMode: 'remote',
queryParam: 'query',
displayField: 'name',//+'type',
valueField: 'name',//+'type',
//valueNotFoundText: 'No Data',
 ,listConfig: {
                loadingText: ' Loading...',
                getInnerTpl: function() {
         return  '{name}'+'<br>'+'<p><font size="1">{type}'+':type</font></p>';
                }
                ,
            }
            ,  listeners: {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for sort of this (simplified working example.)

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    typeAhead: true, // this will simply show the typed text if nothing is found.
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
               '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{abbr}</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ),
    displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="name.length == 0"> ',             
               'no data', // You can return any other additional value or formating here
            '<tpl else>',
               '{name}', // You can return any other additional value or formating here
            '</tpl>',                                  
        '</tpl>'
    ),
    valueNotFoundText: 'no data' // this will be displayed if no record is found after setValue()
});
```

Here's a working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/7/)**

**So how does this work**

Simply set the Template for the dropdown menu (if this is needed at all in your case) and set the template for the display field.

*Both examples are simplified cause I do not know your entire template.*

**Updated examples**

*Note: I would not use `type` as property-name cause this is sort of a reserved name, cause it identifies the type of the field object/primitive*

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name','ctype'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama", "ctype":"AL"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska", "ctype":"AK"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona", "ctype":""}
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    typeAhead: true, // this will simply show the typed text if nothing is found.
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="ctype.length == 0"> ',             
               '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{name}<p><font size="1">no data</font></p></div>',
            '<tpl else>',
               '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{name}{ctype}<p><font size="1">{ctype}</font></p></div>',
            '</tpl>',
        '</tpl>'
    ),
    displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="itype.length == 0"> ',             
               'no data',
            '<tpl else>',
               '{name}', 
            '</tpl>',                                  
        '</tpl>'
    ),
    valueNotFoundText: 'no data', // this will be displayed if no record is found after setValue()
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emptyText config option on in the list config http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-emptyText.  ComboBoxes internal list class BoundList extends from View so it follows the same api.  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig

```
listConfig: {
    emptyText: 'No Data'
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this will display the message when there is no any result coming.. but in my case the name is always returns but type doesn't.. so the result will be: `name:mike type:  ` .. So, when type is null i need it to be 'No Data'.