# Passing information to Ext.data.Model in Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to edit an open source program (and learn Extjs meanwhile) and I encountered a problem about models. I don't want to put code here since it is too long but I can provide if necessary.

So I got a a class which extends Ext.form.Panel and model "PartModel" assigned to it. This model has a string field called "partNumber" along with many other fields.

In this panel I want to choose a part number from a combobox from predefined values at database and assign it to "partNumber".

The problem is I want to assign value that is "displayed" in the combobox.(Not one of store fields, I'm using a custom XTemplate for it)

How can I do it?

Edit: Adding combobox code. I thought adding "dataIndex: 'partNumber'" would be sufficient to do job but this code isn't working at all. I can see Part Numbers strings from combobox but when I choose one and hit save button it doesn't save. (There are many other fields working well with that save button maybe I just need to add another button to save part number?)

```js
{
  xtype: 'combobox',
  dataIndex: 'partNumber',
  fieldLabel: "Part Number",
  labelWidth: 150,
  flex: 1,
  store:{
    xtype: 'store',
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'PartGroupsClasses',
    proxy: getPartGC()},
  queryMode: 'local',
  renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
  tpl:Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate','<tpl for="."><div class="x-boundlist-item">{code}-{descr}-{ccode}-{cdescr}</div></tpl>'),
  displayTpl:Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate','<tpl for=".">{code}{descr}{ccode}{cdescr}</tpl>')
}
```

Edit2: Figured out save button is basically calling following function.

```js
Ext.override(Ext.data.Model, {
    setDataWithAssociations: function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            if (this.fields.containsKey(i)) {
                this.set(i, data[i]);
            }
            if (this.associations.containsKey(i)) {
                var store = this[i]();
                store.add(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: A combobox doesn't have a `dataIndex`. A column has a `dataIndex`, but I don't see a grid. Check out `valueField` and `displayField`.

Comment: @Alexander yes sir you are right, changed dataIndex to valueField:'id' and added name:'partNumber'. Now it actually saves my partNumber value, but saves the Part Number table's id (which is valueField)... I tried valueField:this.getRawData() but crashed the program. I need displayField's value in valueField. Is this possible?

Comment: instead of getRawData(), i meant getRawValue() but still didnt work

Comment: @Alexander What I tried makes no sense since I need a field for valueField. Since I can't change the how program saves the values, changing my combobox model and adding it a display field might be a better choice.... But do I need to change my database and add a new column to it, in order to get a new field?

Comment: So instead of using `displayField: 'partNumber'` you're using a tpl, and you want to set the partNumber model value to `{code}{descr}{ccode}{cdescr}`, right?

Comment: @incutonez That's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this... in your combobox's model, add an extra field that makes use of the [`convert`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert) function to create your displayValue, and then in your combobox, just use that value for your `displayValue` property.

**Model**

```
Ext.define('MyComboModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'code',
      type: 'string'
    },
    {
      name: 'desc',
      type: 'string'
    },
    {
      name: 'ccode',
      type: 'string'
    },
    {
      name: 'cdesc',
      type: 'string'
    },
    {
      name: 'displayValue',
      type: 'string',
      convert: function(value, record) {
        return record.get('code') +
          record.get('desc') +
          record.get('ccode') +
          record.get('cdesc');
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

**Combo**

```
    xtype: 'combobox',
    name: 'Field2',
    valueField: 'displayValue',
    displayField: 'displayValue',
    fieldLabel: 'Field2',
    queryMode: 'local',
```

[Full example.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1fec)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks sir.

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I dont thing your question is clear enough for a clear answer...
I am unclear on your objective but if you want to have something display on store and behind it have the value on the file please take a look see if this examples helps

### Store

`this.data = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {fields: ['id', 'data'],
                            data: [{id: 1, data: 'data1'},
                                {id: 2, data: 'data2'},
                                {id: 3, data: 'data3'},
                                {id: 4, data: 'data4'}]});`

### Combo

```
xtype:'Combobox',
name:'wtv',
displayField: 'data',
valueField: 'id'
```

It will display the combo with data but if you get the combo with the selection path and do for example

### Selector

```
refs: [{
ref:Combo
selector:'Panel Combobox[name=wtv]'
}]
```

Later you can do something like 
`Panel.getCombo().getValue()` and  it will not 
give you back the displayed field (Data) but it will give the id.

Sorry for bad formating! Hope it helps

Comment: When you say save... you mean choose one on the combobox and deselecting? or do you got a button?

Comment: this panel has lots of fields in it and has a save button at bottom which basically calls this function:setDataWithAssociations: function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            if (this.fields.containsKey(i)) {
                this.set(i, data[i]);
            }
            if (this.associations.containsKey(i)) {
                var store = this[i]();
                store.add(data[i]);
            }
        }
    } thats why I think this should also save my combobox with other fields of panel

Comment: Hmm... I am kidda noob myself... Maybe listener of the save button is not getting the data of the combobox?
Sorry kidda out of ideias, and your code doesnt reveals much :X

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891324/extjs-combo-diplay-value-if-value-is-not-found
See  if this helps you

Comment: my problem is not with combobox, but saving the displaytext to another store

Comment: how about you read my post for combo values...? Did you even read? (Not the link but what i posted here)

Comment: Of course i read. But I didn't understand selector part.(where to put that code) But anyway my issue is different now (as described in the comments of my post) I need to put displayField instead of valueField now

Comment: Ok, the ref, is used for getting a path of the combobox on the controller... of the view... But i  am not sure you use MVC... Extjs highly supports this feature... You dont need the selector for getting the combobox i think you can do something like 
`var combo = Ext.getCmp('Panelname').getComponent('comboboxname(wtv in the example above');`
later just do
`combo.getValue()` and it will return the value and not the display field if you have assigned them well beforehand
edit: getComponent will only work if is it directChild...
Use 
`find('name', 'wtv')[0];`
As it will look in all childs